# Working with $\bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}_X}$?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-topology, tensor-products

What is the meaning of the tensor product sign in a formula such as $$ A \bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}_X} B $$ where X is a real manifold of arbitrary dimension? B is a orientation sheaf (ultimately a matrix of some 1 and -1 entries?) and A is a cohomology, in the original context.

This is a form of tensor product over the ring of integers, I think, but what would that mean in this context? What could the real manifold X subscript means here, specifically?

EDIT: The type of equation above gives a sheaf in the paper where this is found (goal of the paper is construction of microfunctions). They do not define it anywhere, so I assume it must be standard. Or let's put the question another way, how does the operation differs from $ \bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} $ ?

Comment: Do you have any source? This could mean the constant sheaf.

Comment: What kind of objects are the entries of $B$? What do you mean by "$A$ is a homology"?

Comment: B is the sheaf of orientation of manifold X. A is the nth cohomology of the sheaf of holomorphic functions defined on the neighborhood of X. Perhaps I am wrong in interpreting B to be a sort of matrix of -1 or 1 entries?